# Why does my code not work in Safari or Opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, opera

There is a function in `js` which displays messages to the table (messages are stored in `json`). In Google Chrome, it works, but Safari, Opera or Microsoft Edge - no!
There is a mistake in code which is associated with the call to `setTimeout (callback, 5000)`(nothing is sent to the callback).So, `For (var i = 0; i <respond.length; i ++)` will not work since `respond === undefined`.

**But why is it so?**

```js
callback(
  [{
      "time": "1500303264",
      "user": "qwe",
      "message": "we",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "time": "1500303987",
      "user": "Max",
      "message": "q",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]);

function smile(mess) {
  var smile = ":)";
  var graficSmile = "<img src = './image/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>";
  var string_with_replaced_smile = mess.replace(smile, graficSmile);

  var sad = ":("
  var graficSad = "<img src = './image/Sad.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>";
  var string_with_replaced_smile_and_sad = string_with_replaced_smile.replace(sad, graficSad);

  return string_with_replaced_smile_and_sad;
}

$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
var exists = [];

function callback(respond) {
  var timeNow = Date.now();

  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];

    if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

    var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
    var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);

    if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
      var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');

      var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
      var dateArray = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()]
      var res = dateArray.map(function(x) {
        return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
      }).join(":");

      $('#messages').append(rowClone);
      $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
      $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
      $('.message', rowClone).html(smile(data.message));
      $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

      exists.push(data.id);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function(){callback(respond)}, 5000);
}
```

```css
.scroller {
  width: 490px;
  height: 255px;
  max-height: 255px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table#messages {
  min-height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fffecd;
  border: none;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

table#messages::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

tr {
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
}

td.time,
td.name {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

td.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form#text_submit {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input#text {
  width: 370px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fffecd;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

input#submit {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 21px;
  margin-top: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 95px;
  background: #635960;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
      <td class="name"></td>
      <td class="message"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<form method="POST" id="easyForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Opera
[image: Opera]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Since it is assumed that the `var exists` - array, but the value of the array (`[]`) is assigned to it only later, after the call `$.getJSON(...)`. So, when `callback` is called for the first time value `[]` is not set for `exists`.We just need to move `var exists` above the first call of `callback.`
2. When `callback` is called by the timer, nothing is passed to it. But timer needs to reread the messages from the file and display them on the screen.So, instead `setTimeout(function(){callback(respond)}, 5000);` we need `setTimeout(function(){$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);}, 5000);`.

```js
var exists = [];
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);

function callback(respond) {
  var timeNow = Date.now();

  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];

    if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

    var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
    var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);

    if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
      var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');

      var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
      var dateArray = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()]
      var res = dateArray.map(function(x) {
        return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
      }).join(":");

      $('#messages').append(rowClone);
      $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
      $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
      $('.message', rowClone).html(smile(data.message));
      $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

      exists.push(data.id);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer for any one not adept, just say that you added a time out and why.

Comment: @MartinBarker Yes.Look new answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since `callback` requires an array to be passed as an argument, `setTimeout` must  ensure that when it calls `callback`, it passes the array.

Change

`setTimeout(callback, 5000);`

to

`setTimeout(function(){callback(respond)}, 5000);`

which allows callback to be called with an argument as the body of an anonymous function that will be called by `setTimeout`.

Also, as a side note, if you used `respond.forEach()` instead of a counting `for` loop, the code would be much cleaner:

```
   respond.forEach(function(data) {

    if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

    var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
    var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);

    if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
      var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');

      var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
      var dateArray = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()]
      var res = dateArray.map(function(x) {
        return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
      }).join(":");

      $('#messages').append(rowClone);
      $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
      $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
      $('.message', rowClone).html(smile(data.message));
      $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

      exists.push(data.id);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I introduced your edits, but now the code has stopped displaying messages at all. although the error is no  there)

Comment: But where is the value of `respond` supposed to come from? In the current state of the code in the question, the `setTimeout()` passes `respond` but it's not defined anywhere. (It looks like it's supposed to come back from a `$.getJSON()` call, so I'm not sure how the timeout thing even figures in.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but what is wrong if this  does not appear?